# web3.utils.hexToAscii return junk data

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

this.web3.utils.hexToAscii('') return junk data like return **oÚ©J$ìGðK[!Ä¿ÎßyVoÙ,©ù³Ì1ØõDcS{¸³)¼ àToken transfer101** insted of actual data "**0.0007 Token transfer 101 **".

**Example:**

this.web3.utils.hexToAscii('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');

**Actual behavior**

return oÚ©J$ìGðK[!Ä¿ÎßyVoÙ,©ù³Ì1ØõDcS{¸³)¼ àToken transfer101

**Expected behavior**

0.0007 Token transfer 101

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The input data is not hex representation of the expected string, that's why the `hexToAscii()` function returns unexpected output.

It works correctly for the actual hex-encoded string:

```
const decoded = web3.utils.hexToAscii("0x302E3030303720546F6B656E207472616E7366657220313031");
console.log(decoded);
```